# Change AppBar's menu text

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have the following AppBar.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button x:Name="switchMeasurementMode" AutomationProperties.Name = "Breath rate" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Click="switchMeasurementMode_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

It looks like this

[image]

I tend to change its text during run-time with the following C# code

```
    private void switchMeasurementMode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.switchMeasurementMode.Name = "111";
    }
```

But the button text is not changed. Is there anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the default styles for AppBar in Windows 8 C# projects, then you have to change the attached property **AutomationProperties.Name** either in XAML using:

> AutomationProperties.Name = "new name"

or in code using:

> Button.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "new value");
>   or
>   AutomationProperties.SetName(Button, "new value");

Comment: Great! `AutomationProperties.SetName(this.switchMeasurementMode, "111");` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The button is a content control.  You set the Content property to change the content.

```
 this.switchMeasurementMode.Content= "111";
```

The Name property is how you set the programmatic "handle" for the Button.  You use the name in the code editor to modify the control.  In your case, you are changing the name, which means you loose the ability to say this.switchMeasurementMode...

FYI, content can be more than just text.  Most XAML elements can be added as content.